# UITableViewCell not showing image downloaded from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have table that is a byproduct of “Search Bar and Search Display Controller” for which the UITableViewCell is custom made from xib. Below is the code for the Cell. I am not able to spot why the image is not showing. Will someone please help me troubleshoot? All the other data are showing, except the content of the imageView.

`.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BCDDogSearchTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dogImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *dogDescriptionView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *imageURL;


@end
```

`.m`

```
#import "BCDDogTableViewCell.h"
#import "FICImageCache.h"

@interface BCDDogTableViewCell()

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end

@implementation BCDDogTableViewCell


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)setImageURL:(NSString *)imageURL
{
    _imageURL=imageURL;
    [self startDownloadingImage];
}

-(void)startDownloadingImage
{
    self.image=nil;
    if (self.imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"The imageURL is %@",self.imageURL);

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task =
            [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                           completionHandler:^(NSURL *localfile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                               if (!error) {
                                   if ([request.URL isEqual:self.imageURL]) {//check in case things have changed somehow
                                       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localfile]];
                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{self.image=image;});//ui thread.
                                   }
                               }else NSLog(@"loading image error: %@",error);
                           }];
        [task resume];
    }

}

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSLog(@"set image to the image view");
    self.dogImageView.image=image;
}

-(UIImage *)image
{
     NSLog(@"get image from imageView");
    return self.dogImageView.image;
}

-(UIImageView *) dogImageView
{
    if (!_dogImageView) _dogImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    return _dogImageView;
}


@end
```

**UPDATE**

I added more logging to the following snippet

```
if (!error) {
  NSLog(@"Completion block before if");
  if ([request.URL isEqual:self.imageURL]) {//check in case things have changed somehow
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localfile]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{self.image=image;});//ui thread.
  }else{
    NSLog(@"request url %@",request.URL);
    NSLog(@"self url %@", self.imageURL);
  }
}else NSLog(@"loading image error: %@",error);
```

And based on the logging, `if ([request.URL isEqual:self.imageURL])` keeps returning false although the two urls printed in the else clause are equal in content.

So I removed that if check and suddenly the image is showing. But I am afraid it's only working because I have one row in my table. So does anyone know why the check is failing while clearly it is the same url inside?

Comment: One thing you should not have is that last method, dogImageView. dogImageView is an IBOutlet, you shouldn't be creating one in code.

Comment: @rdelmar I removed it but the problem persists.

Comment: Is your log inside setImage firing? If you log image inside that method, is it nil?

Comment: Are you calling -(void)setImageURL:(NSString *)imageURL in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, in my if statement I was comparing a url with a string.

```
if ([request.URL isEqual:self.imageURL])
```

Thanks to everyone for helping.